# SOAP Envelope Contains Encoded Characters When Inspected in Debugger

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, xsd

I have a proxy calling a WCF service. In order to inspect the SOAP envelope I'm sending the service, I implemented a class that inherits from `IClientMessageInspector` and set a breakpoint on my implementation of the `BeforeSendRequest` method.

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
   return request.ToString();
}
```

When I hit the breakpoint, I'm able to inspect the SOAP envelope, but multiple elements in the SOAP body seems to be serialized incorrectly. `<`, `>`, etc. are encoded, when the rest of the SOAP envelope looks like regular XML.

```
<s:Body>
    <ICON_MessageTrain xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        &lt;ICON_MessageTrain xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns=""&gt;
            &lt;SID_Inquiry&gt;
                &lt;SID_Header&gt;
                    &lt;SSN&gt;999999999&lt;/SSN&gt;
                    &lt;requestorStatePostal&gt;NY&lt;/requestorStatePostal&gt;
                    &lt;netid&gt;0&lt;/netid&gt;
                    &lt;userid&gt;0&lt;/userid&gt;
                    &lt;termid&gt;0&lt;/termid&gt;
                    &lt;status&gt;R&lt;/status&gt;
                &lt;/SID_Header&gt;
            &lt;/SID_Inquiry&gt;
        &lt;/ICON_MessageTrain&gt;
    </ICON_MessageTrain>
</s:Body>
```

I think this is happening when I serialize the a class to XML with the following code.

```
XmlSerializer messageTrainSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ICON_MessageTrain));
var serializedMessageTrain = "";

var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = false,
    OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
    Encoding = encoding
};

using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, xmlWriterSettings))
    {
        messageTrainSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, iconMessageTrain);
        serializedMessageTrain = stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

I build an object that I eventually send to the service with the following contract:

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
public class UiIconRequestData
{
    public UiIconRequestData(string source, string application, string ICON_MessageTrain)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.application = application;
        this.ICON_MessageTrain = ICON_MessageTrain;
    }

    [MessageHeader]
    public string source;

    [MessageHeader]
    public string application;

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string ICON_MessageTrain;
}
```

If the issue with the encoded characters is happening due to the way I'm serializing the class, how should I serialize it without encoding the characters?

Comment: You can encode the `Message`. Convert to an array of byes and then convert to string using the `Encoding` object, like this:  
`var enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"); var xml = enc.GetString(arrayMessage);`

Comment: @RicardoPontual, when you say encode the ```message```, are you referring to the whole ```MessageContract```, or just the ```MessageBodyMember```?

Comment: The  message body, in `Message` object. As you're implementing `IClientMessageInspector`, you can get the message in a couple of methods, `BeforeSendRequest` for instance